# Back and Forth relations on linear orderings.

Tags: order-theory, model-theory, computability

I am going through C. Ashe and J. Knight *Computable structures and the Hyperarithmetic Hierarchy* and am stuck at proving one of their Lemmas on back and forth relations and linear orderings (Chapter 15.3.3.).

Ashe and Knight define the *standard back and forth relation* as follows. I will only state the (slightly simpler) definition for finite languages here.

> For two structure $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ in a finite language $L$ and tuples $\overline a\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\overline b \in \mathcal{B}$ of the same size we define the relation $\leq_\beta$ by induction.
>
> - $(\mathcal{A},\overline a) \leq_0 (\mathcal{B},\overline b)$ if and only if all quantifier free formulas $\phi(\overline x)$ true of $\overline{a}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ are true of $\overline{b}$ in $\mathcal{B}$,
> - for $\beta\geq 1$, $(\mathcal{A},\overline a)\leq_\beta (\mathcal B,\overline b)$ if and only if, for each $\overline{d}\in \mathcal{B}$ and each $0\leq \alpha<\beta$, there exists $\overline{c}\in \mathcal{A}$ of the same length such that $(\mathcal{B},\overline b \overline d)\leq_\alpha (\mathcal{A},\overline a \overline c)$.

The Lemma I am struggling with is the following.

> **Lemma 15.7.** *Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are linear orderings. Let $\overline{a}=(a_0,\cdots, a_{n-1})$, $\overline{b}=(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1})$ be increasing tuples from $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, respectively, and let $\mathcal {A}_i, \mathcal{B}_i$ be intervals such that 
>   $$ \mathcal{A}=\mathcal{A}_0 + \{a_0\}+\mathcal{A}_1+\cdots+ \{a_{n-1}\} + \mathcal{A}_n,$$
>   $$ \mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}_0 + \{b_0\}+\mathcal{B}_1+\cdots+ \{b_{n-1}\} + \mathcal{B}_n.$$
>   Then $(\mathcal{A},\overline a)\leq_\beta (\mathcal{B},\overline b)$ if and only if for all $0\leq i\leq n$, $\mathcal{A}_i\leq_\beta \mathcal{B}_i$.*

They claim that this is easily proved by induction on $\beta$. For $\beta=0$ it is easy, but I am stuck at the induction step. I was trying using the fact that $(\mathcal A,\overline a)\leq_\beta (\mathcal B,\overline b)$ iff $\Sigma_\beta^{\mathrm{in}}\mbox{-}tp(\overline b)\subseteq \Sigma_\beta^{\mathrm{in}}\mbox{-}tp(\overline a)$ (Proposition 15.1 in their book) but could not come up with anything substantial. (Here $\Sigma_\beta^{\mathrm{in}}\mbox{-}tp^{\mathcal{B}}(\overline b)$ is the set of infinitary $\Sigma_\beta$ formulas true of $\overline b$ in $\mathcal{B}$.)

Comment: Please define some of your notation. What is the meaning of  $\leq_{\beta}$. Is it just embedding ?

Comment: Sorry, I added the definitions to my question. I hope that it is clearer now.

Comment: In the def'n of $\leq_{\beta}$ there is no def'n of  $(B,\bar b,\bar d)\leq_{0} (A,\bar a,\bar c)$ so how do we know whether $(A,\bar a)\leq_1 (B,\bar b) $ ?

Comment: If $\overline b$ and $\overline d$ are tuples of size $m$ and $n$, respectively, then $\overline b, \overline d$ is the canonical tuple of size $m+n$ obtained by concatenation of $\overline b$ and $\overline d$. This is the notation used in _Computable structures and the hyperarithmetic hierarchy_. If I recall correctly this is often written without comma and I agree that this notation might be confusing. I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the argument for the inductive step $\beta\geq 1$.

Suppose $(\mathcal{A},\overline{a})\leq_\beta (\mathcal{B},\overline{b})$. We want to show that $\mathcal{A}_i\leq_\beta \mathcal{B}_i$ for all $i$. By definition, we need to show that for any $\overline{d}\in \mathcal{B}_i$ (which we might as well assume is in ascending order - if you don't believe this, you should check it) and $\alpha<\beta$, there is $\overline{c}$ such that $(\mathcal{B}_i,\overline{d})\leq_\alpha(\mathcal{A}_i,\overline{c})$. Well, since $(\mathcal{A},\overline{a})\leq_\beta (\mathcal{B},\overline{b})$, there is some tuple $\overline{c}$ such that $(\mathcal{B},\overline{b}\overline{d})\leq_\alpha (\mathcal{A},\overline{a}\overline{c})$. In particular, the quantifier-free types of $\overline{b}\overline{d}$ and $\overline{a}\overline{c}$ agree, so the elements of $\overline{c}$ are in increasing order and are all in $\mathcal{A}_i$. So we have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A} &= \mathcal{A}_0 + \{a_0\} + \dots + \{a_{i-1}\} + (\mathcal{A}_i^0 + \{c_0\} + \mathcal{A}_i^1 + \{c_1\} + \dots \{c_{k-1}\} + \mathcal{A}_i^k) + \{a_i\} + \dots + \mathcal{A}_n\\
\mathcal{B} &= \mathcal{B}_0 + \{b_0\} + \dots + \{b_{i-1}\} + (\mathcal{B}_i^0 + \{d_0\} + \mathcal{B}_i^1 + \{d_1\} + \dots \{d_{k-1}\} + \mathcal{B}_i^k) + \{b_i\} + \dots + \mathcal{B}_n
\end{align*}
where the suborders in parentheses are subdivisions of $\mathcal{A}_i$ and $\mathcal{B}_i$. Now by the inductive hypothesis, since $(\mathcal{B},\overline{b}\overline{d})\leq_\alpha (\mathcal{A},\overline{a}\overline{c})$, we have $\mathcal{B}_i^j\leq_\alpha \mathcal{A}_i^j$ for all $1\leq j\leq k$, and by the inductive hypothesis again, this implies that $(\mathcal{B}_i,\overline{d})\leq_\alpha (\mathcal{A}_i,\overline{c})$.

The converse direction is similar: We assume that $\mathcal{A}_i\leq_\beta\mathcal{B}_i$ for all $i$. To show that $(\mathcal{A},\overline{a})\leq_\beta (\mathcal{B},\overline{b})$, we pick $\overline{d}$ from $\mathcal{B}$ and $\alpha<\beta$, and we want to find $\overline{c}$ such that that $(\mathcal{B},\overline{b}\overline{d})\leq_\alpha (\mathcal{A},\overline{a}\overline{c})$. This time, we break up the tuple $\overline{d}$ into the subtuples which land in each interval $\mathcal{B}_i$, find corresponding tuples in the $\mathcal{A}_i$, and apply the inductive hypothesis twice as above.